# find out missing stored procedures in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one big projects which is  worked by many developers. WE have git for version control of codes but we are having difficulty for version controls of tables and stored procedure. Everytime i have to take backup from main server and restore database on my local server  but still there are 100+ stored procedures. I just need to sync my stored procedure with them and their with mine.

Is their any way to find out the stored procedure which is their server but non mine and vice versa?

all of my procedures start with **sp_**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is as below

- Take back up from your server
- Restore it to your local server where your local database resides
- say db1 is the database you restored just now and db2 is the database you already have in local server

  If you need to find out the stored procedure which is in db1 but not in db2 then fire the sql below

> ```
> SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME
> FROM db1.information_schema.routines
> WHERE routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
>   AND Left(ROUTINE_NAME, 3) IN ('sp_',
>                                 'xp_',
>                                 'ms_') EXCEPT
>   SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME
>   FROM db2.information_schema.routines WHERE routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
>   AND Left(ROUTINE_NAME, 3) IN ('sp_',
>                                 'xp_',
>                                 'ms_')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have to do this in two steps

1. Create a link to the server from your sql instance using the script below
   Note to change [Server IP] with your SQL Server IP also [User ID] and [Password] with valid SQL credentials.

   ```
   /* Object:  LinkedServer [Server IP]    Script Date: 12/12/2013 12:29:41 */
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
     @server = N'[Server IP]',
     @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'

   /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ## */
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
     @rmtsrvname=N'[Server IP]',
     @useself=N'False',
     @locallogin=NULL,
     @rmtuser=N'[User Id]',
     @rmtpassword='[Password]'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'collation compatible',
     @optvalue=N'false'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'data access',
     @optvalue=N'true'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'dist',
     @optvalue=N'false'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'pub',
     @optvalue=N'false'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'rpc',
     @optvalue=N'false'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'rpc out',
     @optvalue=N'false'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'sub',
     @optvalue=N'false'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'connect timeout',
     @optvalue=N'0'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'collation name',
     @optvalue=NULL

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'lazy schema validation',
     @optvalue=N'false'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'query timeout',
     @optvalue=N'0'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'use remote collation',
     @optvalue=N'true'

   GO

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
     @server=N'[Server IP]',
     @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion',
     @optvalue=N'true'

   GO
   ```
2. Execute the following Query. Here change [Server IP] to correct IP and [Database] to your main server Database name. Execute this query on your local server.

   ```
       SELECT *
       FROM   [Server IP].[Database].sys.objects
       WHERE  type = 'p'
              AND name NOT IN (SELECT name
                               FROM   sys.objects)
   ```

Comment: The advantage of this method is that you can avoid backup and restore every time you need to get latest stored procedures. This is a live sp comparison method provided you have enough access to the server.